# Deriving the Dirac delta function sifting property from a top hat function

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, dirac-delta

I am trying to derive the Dirac delta function from a top hat function whose width tends to $0$ and has an area of $1$. Here is my working below and let me know if there is anything wrong with it:

[image]

Comment: It looks like what you mean is you're trying to derive the sifting property of the Dirac delta. You don't derive mathematical objects; you derive the facts about them.

Comment: @J.G. yes, I can try to update the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to prove $\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_{q-a}^{q+a}\frac{1}{2a}f(x)dx=f(q)$ (provided $f$ is continuous at $q$; the last $=$ in this answer uses that). Before trying, let's note how plausible this is; it says that if you average $f$ over $[q-a,\,q+a]$, as $a\to0^+$ the mean becomes $f(q)$. By L'Hôpital,$$\lim_{a\to0^+}\frac{\int_{q-a}^{q+a}f(x)dx}{2a}=\lim_{a\to0^+}\frac{f(q+a)+f(q-a)}{2}=f(q).$$

Comment: So before my Taylor expansion everything is okay, i.e. the top hat function is correctly defined and the steps leading to the Taylor expansion are correct?

Comment: @Σbaryon Taking $h=1/(2a)$, you worked with a correct example of what we call a family of nascent delta functions. But no Taylor expansions are needed, because integrals involving the Dirac delta are *defined* as the $a\to0^+$ half-limit of what nascent deltas get.